# Does TypeScript supports ducktype?

Tags: typescript

I see contradicting info about this. https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/classes.html (go to inheritance section) here says it's supported but I see my code failing to compile in TypeScript [playGround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Point%7B%0D%0A%09x%3Anumber%3B%20%0D%0A%09y%3Anumber%3B%0D%0A%09constructor(x%3Anumber%2C%20y%3Anumber)%7B%0D%0A%09this.x%20%3D%20x%3B%0D%0A%09this.y%20%3D%20y%20%3B%09%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09add(point%3APoint)%7B%0D%0A%09%20return%20new%20Point(this.x%20%2B%20point.x%20%2C%20this.y%20%2B%20point.y)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Point3D%20extends%20Point%7B%0D%0A%09z%3Anumber%3B%0D%0A%09constructor(x%3Anumber%2C%20y%3Anumber%2C%20z%3Anumber)%7B%0D%0A%09%09super(x%2Cy)%3B%0D%0A%09%09this.z%20%3D%20z%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09add(point3d%3APoint3D)%7B%0D%0A%09%09var%20point2D%20%3D%20super.add(%20%7Bpoint3d.x%2C%20point3d.y%7D)%3B%0D%0A%09%09return%20new%20Point3D(point2D.x%2C%20point2D.y%2C%20this.z)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A)

```
class Point{
    x:number; 
    y:number;
    constructor(x:number, y:number){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y ;    
    }

    add(point:Point){
     return new Point(this.x + point.x , this.y + point.y);
    }
}

class Point3D extends Point{
    z:number;
    constructor(x:number, y:number, z:number){
        super(x,y);
        this.z = z;
    }

    add(point3d:Point3D){
        // Error does not support duct type.
        var point2D = super.add( {point3d.x, point3d.y}); 
        return new Point3D(point2D.x, point2D.y, this.z);
    }
}
```

Comment: TypeScript is actually not duck typed, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Won't be in your case good enough, to simply pass the `Point` instance as is:

```
add(point3d:Point3D){
    // Error does not support duct type.
    //var point2D = super.add( {point3d.x, point3d.y}); 

    var point2D = super.add(point3d);
```

Because super simply accepts point

```
add(point:Point){...
```

and Point3d is Point

```
class Point3D extends Point{
```

There is [updated playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Point%7B%0D%0A%09x%3Anumber%3B%20%0D%0A%09y%3Anumber%3B%0D%0A%09constructor(x%3Anumber%2C%20y%3Anumber)%7B%0D%0A%09this.x%20%3D%20x%3B%0D%0A%09this.y%20%3D%20y%20%3B%09%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09add(point%3APoint)%7B%0D%0A%09%20return%20new%20Point(this.x%20%2B%20point.x%20%2C%20this.y%20%2B%20point.y)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Point3D%20extends%20Point%7B%0D%0A%09z%3Anumber%3B%0D%0A%09constructor(x%3Anumber%2C%20y%3Anumber%2C%20z%3Anumber)%7B%0D%0A%09%09super(x%2Cy)%3B%0D%0A%09%09this.z%20%3D%20z%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09add(point3d%3APoint3D)%7B%0D%0A%09%09var%20point2D%20%3D%20super.add(point3d)%3B%0D%0A%09%09return%20new%20Point3D(point2D.x%2C%20point2D.y%2C%20this.z)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A)

In case, we would like to use the duck typing in full strength, we should introduce interface

```
interface IPoint{
    x:number; 
    y:number;
}
```

and consume that in the add method

```
add(point:IPoint){
 return new Point(this.x + point.x , this.y + point.y);
}
```

and finally, we can use duck typing:

```
var point2D = super.add({x: point3d.x, y: point3d.y});
```

Adjusted [example is here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20IPoint%7B%0D%0A%09x%3Anumber%3B%20%0D%0A%09y%3Anumber%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Point%7B%0D%0A%09x%3Anumber%3B%20%0D%0A%09y%3Anumber%3B%0D%0A%09constructor(x%3Anumber%2C%20y%3Anumber)%7B%0D%0A%09this.x%20%3D%20x%3B%0D%0A%09this.y%20%3D%20y%20%3B%09%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09add(point%3AIPoint)%7B%0D%0A%09%20return%20new%20Point(this.x%20%2B%20point.x%20%2C%20this.y%20%2B%20point.y)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Point3D%20extends%20Point%7B%0D%0A%09z%3Anumber%3B%0D%0A%09constructor(x%3Anumber%2C%20y%3Anumber%2C%20z%3Anumber)%7B%0D%0A%09%09super(x%2Cy)%3B%0D%0A%09%09this.z%20%3D%20z%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09add(point3d%3APoint3D)%7B%0D%0A%09%09var%20point2D%20%3D%20super.add(%7Bx%3A%20point3d.x%2C%20y%3A%20point3d.y%7D)%3B%0D%0A%09%09return%20new%20Point3D(point2D.x%2C%20point2D.y%2C%20this.z)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A)

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript is actually not [duck typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), but rather [structurally typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system). The difference is basically that duck-typing only cares about that the specific members that you access in run-time is there, while structural typing requires you to fulfill the *whole* contract of an object that you want act as a specific interface/type.

When you are sending in the object `{x:point3d.x, y:point3d.y}`, TypeScript requires that this object is structurally compatible with `Point`, which it isn't since it does not have an add-method.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create an object `{x:number, y:number}` and call it a Point. However, a Point is of type `{x:number, y:number, add:(point:Point)=>Point}`. If you introduce an 'add' property that matches that signature it will work.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things going on here.

1. Your syntax is wrong. `{point3d.x, point3d.y}` should be `{x: point.x, y: point.y}` if you are trying to create an object.
2. You cannot ducktype in this case because your object does not have an `add` method (the compiler will tell you this). Below I created an interface called `IPoint` to satisfy the compiler.

See my solution:

```
interface IPoint {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

class Point{
    x:number; 
    y:number;
    constructor(x:number, y:number){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y ;    
    }

    add(point:IPoint){
     return new Point(this.x + point.x , this.y + point.y);
    }
}

class Point3D extends Point{
    z:number;
    constructor(x:number, y:number, z:number){
        super(x,y);
        this.z = z;
    }

    add(point:Point3D){
        var point2D = super.add({x: point.x, y: point.y});
        return new Point3D(point2D.x, point2D.y, this.z);
    }
}
```